# Would only those 1% of all test subjects in the Matrix choose the red pill offered by the Zion Resistance?

Tags: the-matrix

Can I infer from the Architect's speech that those who would choose the red pill offered by the Zion Resistance will be solely from the 1% of all test subjects? The rest 99% would choose the blue pill? Even though the Zion Resistance has no idea how the Matrix really works.

> The Architect: As I was saying, she stumbled upon a solution whereby
>   nearly 99 percent of the test subjects accepted the program
>   provided they were given a choice - even if they were only aware of it
>   at a near-unconscious level.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're wanting to know. Are you asking whether the Zionese rebels actively seek out those who struggle to accept the Matrix?

Comment: No, I'm asking it from the machine's perspective. @Richard

Comment: It's unclear whether the 1% are people like Neo with "a splinter in their mind" or the 1% are people who either die when jacked in or simply can't be jacked in (when Smith talks about the Paradise Matrix he says "no-one would accept the program - entire crops were lost").

Answer (score 3):

It's not entirely apparent in the film, but the reality of the Matrix is that only those within the 1% group are *capable* of exiting into reality. The others (the 99%) are those that are so [inured](https://youtu.be/pIoMXYBztdg?t=25s) in the world of the Matrix that if shown what's outside the Matrix, will die. This is referred to in-universe as 'popping' and is something we see in the Matrix Comic "[Saviors](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Saviors)"

[image]

It's perhaps also not apparent that the red pill and the blue pill aren't solely *metaphorical symbols of acceptance*, they're **genuine actual pills that have physiological effects**. The red pill disrupts your 'carrier signal' and causes the Matrix to reject you. The blue pill seems to be some sort of sedative.

**Giving someone from the 99% the *choice of pills* is essentially meaningless since if they accept the the red pill from you, it will kill them.**

By the same token, a 1%er who accepts the blue pill will still remain capable of  exiting the Matrix safely, they'll just lack the means to do so, as we see in "[A Life Less Empty](http://web.archive.org/web/20040614052823/http://whatisthematrix.warnerbros.com/cmp/ted_01.html)"

[image]

Comment: Richard I should have bought the comics when I was 11. But I was just that, 11.

There no where to be found. Do you know where I can find a copy?

Comment: @Sidhartha - You can find almost all of the comics online [here](http://gnorb.net/389/the-matrix-comics-online) along with the stories Goliath and System Freeze.

Answer (score 0):

They generally would form part of that 1% probability group. The resistance clearly has a reasonable idea of how the matrix works given that they can identify people likely to be in that 1% and perform many operator level functions within the matrix.

Although as Cypher mentions, the details of the choice and it's ramifications weren't made that clear by the resistance and later on he decides he'd rather be jacked back in.

The test subjects are most likely all dead and from beta versions of the matrix. I'm brought to mind of some scenes from the animatrix involving human experimentation.